# Determine under which conditions the formula $\phi[t/x]\leftrightarrow \forall x ((x=t)\rightarrow \phi)$ is logically true

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I am stucked at this problem for a long time:

> Determine under which conditions the following first-order formula is logically true
>
> $$\phi[t/x]\leftrightarrow \forall x ((x=t)\rightarrow \phi)$$
>
> where $t$ is a term, $x$ is a variable, $\phi$ is a formula and $\phi[t/x]$ denotes that we are substituting the term $t$ in place of the free occurrences of the variable $x$ in the string $\phi$ and that none of the variables in $t$ becomes bound to one of the quantifieres in $\phi$ (If any).

---

For the $\rightarrow$ side we can deduce as follows: let $K=\{\phi[t/x]\}$, now (1) $K\vdash \phi[t/x]$ (2) $K\vdash \phi[t/x]\rightarrow ((t=t)\rightarrow \phi[t/x])$ (3) $K\vdash ((t=t)\rightarrow \phi[t/x])$ , Now I do not know how to conclude $K\vdash \forall x((x=t)\rightarrow \phi)$ ? Which axioms should I use?

Thanks for any hint/help.

Comment: For the $\rightarrow$ side we can deduce as follows: let $K=\{\phi[t/x]\}$, now (1) $K\vdash \phi[t/x]$ (2) $K\vdash \phi[t/x]\rightarrow ((t=t)\rightarrow \phi[t/x])$ (3) $K\vdash ((t=t)\rightarrow \phi[t/x])$ , Now I do not know how to conclude $K\vdash \forall x((x=t)\rightarrow \phi)$ ? Which axioms should I use?

Comment: Yes if we have this axiom, the proof works out. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Picking up from your step (1), you could also say: $K\vdash (x=t)\to(\phi [t/x]\to \phi)$ (where $\phi$ is obtained by replacing $t$ by $x$ in zero or more instances in $\phi[t/x]$, i.e. $\phi[x/x]=\phi$). Then by rule T and (1), $K\vdash (x=t)\to\phi$, and generalize on $x$.

Comment: A sufficient condition is that $x$ does not appear free in $t$. I don't think it will be easy or even possible to come up with a useful necessary condition.

Comment: PS: The formula is certainly not always valid: e.g., $(y = x)[x/x]$ (i.e.,  $y = x$) is not logically equivalent to $\forall x (x = x \rightarrow y = x)$.

Comment: @RobArthan - You are right; the needed condition is : $x$ does not occur in $t$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ref to :

- Herbert Enderton, [A Mathematical Introduction to Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=dVncCl_EtUkC&pg=PA130) (2nd ed - 2001), **Ex.13**, page 130.

For $\leftarrow$ :

1) $∀x((x=t) \to \varphi)$ --- assumed

2) $(t=t) \to \varphi[t/x]$ --- from 1) and Enderton's Ax.2 : $∀xα \to α_t^x$, where $t$ is substitutable for $x$ in $\alpha$, and *modus ponens*

3) $\vdash t=t$ --- from *equality* axiom Ax.5

4) $\varphi[t/x]$ --- from 2) and 3) by *mp*

> $\vdash ∀x((x=t) \to \varphi) \to \varphi[t/x]$ --- from 1) and 4) by **Deduction Th**.

---

For $\rightarrow$ :

We need the following :

> **Equality Theorem** [see Shoenfield, page 35]. Let the *term* $b'$ be obtained from the *term* $b$ by replacing some occurrences of $a_1, \ldots ,a_n$ by $a_1', \ldots, a_n'$ respectively, and let the *formula* $A'$ be obtained from the *formula* $A$ by the same type of replacements.
>
> If $\vdash a_1 = a_1', \ldots, \vdash a_n = a_n'$, then $\vdash b = b'$ and $\vdash A \leftrightarrow A'$.

It is provable by induction on the lenght of $b$. We have also [page 36] the

> **Corollary 2**. $\vdash a_1 = a_1' \to \ldots \to a_n = a_n' \to (A[a_1,\ldots, a_n] \leftrightarrow A[a_1',\ldots, a_n'])$.

[It is the "generalization" of Enderton's equality axiom Ax.6 : $x = y \to (α → α')$, where $α$ is atomic and $α'$ is obtained from $α$ by replacing $x$ in zero or more (but not necessarily all) places by $y$.]

1) $\varphi[t/x]$ --- assumed : $x$ does not occur in $t$ and $t$ has replaced **all** the free occurrences of the variable $x$ in $\varphi$

2) $\vdash x=t \to (\varphi \leftrightarrow \varphi[t/x])$ --- from **Coroll.2** above : $\varphi$ is $\varphi[x/x]$

3) $\vdash \varphi[t/x] \to (x=t \to \varphi)$ --- from 2) by *tautological implication* [Enderton's **Lemma 24C (Rule T)**, page 118]

4) $(x=t \to \varphi)$ --- from 1) and 3) by *mp*

5) $\forall x (x=t \to \varphi)$ --- from 5) by **Generalization Th** : $x$ not free in 1), that means : $t$ must replace **all** free occurrences of $x$ in $\varphi$, and that $t$ has no occurrences of $x$

> $\vdash \varphi[t/x] \to \forall x (x=t \to \varphi)$ --- from 1) and 5) by **Deduction Th**.